# which ML algorithm to choose

Tags: machine-learning

In my lab, I have 10 devices which I monitor using each device specific features like.

1. heat-generated
2. power consumed
3. patterns in power consumption

Using a supervised classification model I could classify these devices.

The problem I have is.. in case we add more such different type of devices.. how do I classify them? These device based on the trained model will classify new devices also as one among the classified device, which is untrue. They might have their own patterns.

Is there a way?. and how ?.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at it, it seems like when a new type of device is added to your data-set, you are actually adding a new "**Class**".

In that case, you might have to retrain your model to accommodate the new Classes added to your dataset.

Comment: Yes agreed.. but i want to build a system which doesn't need retraining but still it should be able to classify any newly added device to lab. Is there a way out?, that's the question.